# Executing SPWebApplication.Update with System account throws SecurityException

Tags: sharepoint, securityexception

I`m doing some web.config modifications with  SPWebConfigModification class. When adding them to WebApplication and calling Update to it, it throws me SecurityException, although

- I run code with elevated privilages
  (and open new instance of SPSite)
- my assembly is in GAC
- application pool account is from
  *wss_admin_wpg* group and web.config file has *wss_admin_wpg* write
  permissins.

### Code

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    addProviderProxy(properties);
});
```

where addProviderProxy(SPItemEventProperties properties)

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
  ensureSectionGroup(web);
  ...
}
```

where ensureSectionGroup(SPWeb web)

```
  SPWebApplication webApp = web.Site.WebApplication; 
  ...
  webApp.Update(); <--Throws exception here
```

### Exception Details

```
System.Security.SecurityException was caught
  Message="Piekļuve liegta." //(Translates to something like "Access Denied")
  Source="Microsoft.SharePoint"
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.Update()
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Update()
       at Balticovo.SharePoint.AdjustWebConfigForOutlook.ensureSectionGroup(SPWeb web)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Could you post more information about the exception, e.g. the stack trace?

Comment: Edited. Take a look. Although nothing usefull there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the "Access Denied" error is occurring at SPPersistedObject.Update(), this obviously indicates that there is a problem persisting the object. This is very likely to be a permissions error writing to the SharePoint configuration database (or maybe another SP database).

If possible check the SQL logs or run a SQL Profiler trace to get more information on what account is causing the problem. Check that the account your code is running under has access to the configuration database.

**Update:**

You can give permission to the configuration database by adding the user to the Farm Administrator's group. This gives them db_owner permission on that database which isn't ideal as that means the account can do anything. However there is no other way (that I know of) that can give access to this database.

If this is a major concern, you could change the permissions yourself via SQL Server Management Studio. Ideally use SQL Profiler and devise a new role that gives just the permissions required. Alternatively try adding the account to the `WSS_Content_Application_Pools` role and/or the `data_reader` and `data_writer` roles.

Comment: Yes, turns out that SPPersistedObject writes to configuration database and solved this by adding Application Pool account to Farm Administrators (Central Administration > Operations > Update farm administrator's group)

Not sure how good it is from security standpoint. Maybe someone can comment on this?

Comment: @Janis Veinbergs: Added some info on this. Hopefully someone else can give more.

Answer (score 4):

Try running this in a PowerShell script, then retry your update:

```
$contentService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$contentService.RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied = $false
$contentService.Update()
```

I'm still getting the hang of 2010 permissions, so take it for what it's worth.  According to [Paul Kotlyar](http://unclepaul84.blogspot.com/2010/06/sppersistedobject-xxxxxxxxxxx-could-not.html), that'll help.

Comment: You should run "iisreset" after applying the changes - at least that's what I was missing.